# How can I manage my passwords in org-mode?

Tags: passwords

I've found two projects which deals with managing passwords in org-mode, but they seem abandoned.

I'm also using UNIX PASS with Emacs, but I want rather to manage my passwords in org-mode and then sync one way to UNIX PASS regularly;)

Something like this exists?;)